# Special Character in StackExchange Notification --Inbox

Tags: bug, design

I encountered a special character notification in Stackexchange Notification --Inbox  which is displayed due to presence of apostrophe punctuation mark in a word "it's" below is the screen shot.

> `UPDATE`

it might be because of the shortened statement ending with "'" and right after that "..." is being concatinated....

[image]